# How to enable image caption plugin in CKeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I installed the enhanced image plugin for ckeditor, and place this code on my my page:

```
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
            config.extraPlugins: 'image2',
            height: 450
        } );
    </script>
```

The rich textarea no longer displays, except I use

```
<script> 
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
 </script>
```

Which does not  allow image caption functionality. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Second argument in [`CKEDITOR.replace`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) is config itself. That's why you should define it as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'image2',
    height: 450
} );
```